# Why Flutter version > 1.13.0 cause a smartphone reboot in debug mode only?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

Using the versions of flutter >= 3.13.0 and XCode15, I noticed that my applications in Debug mode made the smartphone reboot by itself (may be a unknown crash). This problem only occurs when I launch applications in Debug mode and does not occur for an application in Release mode.

Having no indication in the debug console or in the systems logs, I see absolutely no or can come the problem.

The reboot of the smartphone occurs on different applications with completely different actions

Versions of flutter < 1.13.0 such as 1.10.6 or 3.7.7, for example, works very well.

Is there a problem on versions of flutter >= 3.13.0 that would cause a reboot of the smarrphone?